# Adding total histogram count to facets in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet-grid

I would like to take a faceted histogram and add text on each plot indicating the total number of observations in that facet. So for carb = 1 the total count would be 7, carb = 2 the total count would be 10 etc.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, stat = "count",fill=as.factor(carb))) + geom_histogram(bins = 8)
p <- p + facet_grid(as.factor(carb) ~ .)
p
```

I can do this with the table function but for more complex faceting how can I do it quickly?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. Maybe is not the most optimal because you have to define the `x` and `y` position for the label (this is done in `Labels` for `x` and in `geom_text()` for `y` with 3). But it can help you:

```
#Other
library(tidyverse)
#Create similar data for labels
Labels <- mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(N=paste0('Number is: ',n()))
#X position
Labels$mpg <- 25
#Plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, stat = "count",fill=as.factor(carb))) + geom_histogram(bins = 8)+
  geom_text(data = Labels,aes(x=mpg,y=3,label=N))+facet_grid(as.factor(carb) ~ .)
```

[image]